# Error when launching spring boot server

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jhipster

Since I tried to connect my app to a postgres database instead of h2 I am getting the following error when starting my jetty/spring boot server :

```
2016-03-02 20:22:15.820  INFO 12954 --- [  restartedMain] com.bau.Application                      : Starting Application on bisupportsMBP4 with PID 12954 (/Users/mbennekrouf/workspace/bau-board/target/classes started by mbennekrouf in /Users/mbennekrouf/workspace/bau-board) 
    2016-03-02 20:22:15.822 DEBUG 12954 --- [  restartedMain] com.bau.Application     : Running with Spring Boot v1.3.1.RELEASE, Spring v4.2.4.RELEASE 
    2016-03-02 20:22:15.822  INFO 12954 --- [  restartedMain] com.bau.Application                      : The following profiles are active: dev,fast 
    2016-03-02 20:22:18.430 DEBUG 12954 --- [  restartedMain] com.bau.config.AsyncConfiguration        : Creating Async Task Executor 
    2016-03-02 20:22:19.052  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026009: XNIO worker was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default worker will be used 
    2016-03-02 20:22:19.159  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used 
    2016-03-02 20:22:19.586  INFO 12954 --- [  restartedMain] com.bau.config.WebConfigurer             : Web application configuration, using profiles: [dev, fast] 
    2016-03-02 20:22:19.586  INFO 12954 --- [  restartedMain] com.bau.config.WebConfigurer          : Web application fully configured 
    2016-03-02 20:22:19.661 DEBUG 12954
--- [  restartedMain] com.bau.config.DatabaseConfiguration     : Configuring Datasource 
    2016-03-02 20:22:19.963  WARN 12954 --- [ bau-Executor-1] c.b.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase     : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup! 
    2016-03-02 20:22:19.965 DEBUG 12954 --- [ bau-Executor-1] c.b.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase     : Started Liquibase in 1 ms objc[12954]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. 
    2016-03-02 20:22:21.956  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory     : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.bau.domain.Task]; using defaults. 
    2016-03-02 20:22:22.024  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory     : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.bau.domain.PlannedTask]; using defaults. 
    2016-03-02 20:22:22.033  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.bau.domain.Project]; using defaults. 
    2016-03-02 20:22:22.043  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory     : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.bau.domain.Devis]; using defaults. 
    2016-03-02 20:22:22.049  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory     : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.bau.domain.Step]; using defaults. 
    2016-03-02 20:22:22.071  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory     : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.bau.domain.Collaborator]; using defaults. 
    2016-03-02 20:22:22.081  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory     : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.bau.domain.Task.plannedTasks]; using defaults. 
    2016-03-02 20:22:22.096  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory     : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.bau.domain.Step.tasks]; using defaults. 
    2016-03-02 20:22:22.101  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.bau.domain.Collaborator.plannedTasks]; using defaults. 
    2016-03-02 20:22:22.105  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory     : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.bau.domain.Project.steps]; using defaults. 
    2016-03-02 20:22:22.114  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory     : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.bau.domain.Project.deviss]; using defaults. 
    2016-03-02 20:22:22.312  INFO 12954 --- [  restartedMain] com.bau.Application     : Running with Spring profile(s) : [dev, fast] 
    2016-03-02 20:22:22.504 WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.bau.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bau.repository.UserRepository com.bau.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bau.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
    Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()} 
    2016-03-02 20:22:22.528 ERROR 12954 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.bau.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bau.repository.UserRepository com.bau.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bau.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
    Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) 
    ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) 
    ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) 
    ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) 
    ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) 
    ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) 
    ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]  at com.bau.Application.main(Application.java:74) [classes/:na]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    ~[na:1.8.0_65]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    ~[na:1.8.0_65]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    ~[na:1.8.0_65]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
    ~[na:1.8.0_65]  at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE] Caused by: 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.bau.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bau.repository.UserRepository com.bau.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bau.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
    Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     ... 20 common frames omitted 
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bau.repository.UserRepository com.bau.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bau.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}  at 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]  at
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) 
    ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     ... 22 common frames omitted 
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bau.repository.UserRepository com.bau.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bau.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}  at 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]    at 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]  ... 33 common frames omitted 
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bau.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}   at 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]    at 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   ... 35 common frames omitted


    2016-03-02 20:22:22.532  WARN 12954 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' is defined)
s
```

I can provide conf files. I do not know not what is interesting to look at.

Comment: what is the table name for your users table? is it 'user'? if so postgres will barf . either way. it's a problem with your userDetailsService

Comment: Improved formatting of error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started your app using dev and fast profiles as shown in your trace.

> The following profiles are active: dev,fast

Fast profile is used to disable Liquibase (see `DatabaseConfiguration` class) when database is not H2 so your database schema has not been created.

```
if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_FAST)) {
            if ("org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource".equals(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())) {
                liquibase.setShouldRun(true);
                log.warn("Using '{}' profile with H2 database in memory is not optimal, you should consider switching to" +
                    " MySQL or Postgresql to avoid rebuilding your database upon each start.", Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_FAST);
            } else {
                liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
            }
        }
```

So either you use only dev profile with Postgresql, or you use dev profile with H2 and prod profile with Postgresql which is probably what you selected when you generated your app.

If you prefer to always use Postgresql in dev, you'd rather edit `.yo-rc.json` file to change `devDatabaseType` and re-generate using `yo jhipster` in your app directory.

Comment: Alright, thanks, it is clearer now. I removed fast, generate my db. How can I re-generate without loosing my changes (new entities + custom codes) ?

Comment: You mostly rely on git for this and merge manually what you want. You can also read our docs about generating an entity a second time https://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-entity/